# Created date should also be included

Tags: feature-request, documentation

There is data mentioned in any topics or review request. I think we should include created data also to check when request was made for new topic.

Initialy what happened with me is i have created 3-4 topics on the first day itself but no one reviewed it, later on same topic got created and now i am getting comments that this topics are already create and its duplication.

Note : i am not talking about **Proposed Changes**, it is already there if you update any topic.